# how to get a part from a string with regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

A string "forum/123/topic/4567".

How can I edit a regular expression to get '123' and '4567' separately?
I have tried lots of methods on the Internet, but nothing works.

Comment: Why not use split?  re seems like overkill here.

Comment: Agreed.  When in doubt, use the thing that is not regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like; `forum/(\d+)/topic/(\d+)`
For regular expressions in python you'll probably be wanting the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), there are even [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#examples).

Although squiguy makes a very good point regarding `re` being overkill here:

```
>>> "forum/123/topic/4567".split("/")
['forum', '123', 'topic', '4567']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r'\w+/(\d+)/\w+/(\d+)
```

should give you two groups containing your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the numbers use `r'0-9+'`. That will give you separated sequences of integers from the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the expression is always exactly that one (except for the numbers), the following code will do:

```
import re
string = "forum/123/topic/4567"
result = re.match("forum/(.*)/topic/(.*)", string)
number1, number2 = result.groups()[:]
```

If the pattern can change, we'll need more information about how. Btw, a very nice explanation about regular expressions can be found at: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm.